sharing variables between a .py file & .ipynb notebook in Spyder
I use spyder editor routineley.
However, for communicating results or archiving them using .ipynb may be good.
I installed the notebook plugin for spyder & it functions normally.
But seemingly it uses a different console. Is there a possibility that it would use the same console as a .py file so that variables would be shared ?
This would help reciprocally testing a code between a .py file & an .ipynb notebook.
